# Mac as proxy for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mac, networking, proxy

I have an ubuntu pc (ip: 132.195.2.2) set up which should be connecting through a switch to my iMac(ip: 132.195.2.1) in order to gain internet access. The iMac has "share internet connection" turned on. I've added the iMac ip in the gateway, DNS and search domain field in the configuration for the eth0 on the ubuntu pc. I also added the iMacs's ip as proxy for all services. I can ping each other pc/Mac, but the only thing my ubuntu pc gets, when calling any URL is my addressbook server web admin page.

Any idea what I've done wrong or how to set this up the right way.

Comment: Can you ping external *IP* addresses? Like Google DNS one: 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: no i can't just tried it

Answer (score 0):

You could try running an SSH SOCKS proxy.  To enable the Mac to be an SSH server, you'd need to go to System Preferences -> Sharing, and enable Remote Logins.  From an Ubuntu terminal, you'd type in `ssh -ND 9999 you@135.195.2.1`.  From there, you can use `127.0.0.1` with port 9999 as a proxy on your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: ok just did that. now i can ping google, but firefox gives me a blank screen. Also apt-get update doesn't get any connection

Comment: Did you change the proxy settings on Firefox?

Comment: i did, but that wouldn't explain why apt-get can't update. I also tried to telnet to google, but i got a time out

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't see why that wouldn't work, but I think a SOCKS proxy is probably the best way to do this.

Comment: Well if it worked it would be pretty cool… but thanks for the idea